# Swift - How to assign var to unknown class

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization, type-alias

Background: I'm creating a game where two objects(Tanks) battle one another. 
On the main menu screen, you choose the two Tanks that will be fighting one another (out of a list of 10 different tanks).
The algorithms for moving and firing the individual/specific Tanks comes from a separate .swift (helper) class for each player that can be chosen from the menu.
(there is no user interaction - all of the code for the battle is inside these classes)

Inside the individual player classes there are only two functions defined: player1TankMove() and player2TankMove().

```
class Player1: gameSceneDelegate {

func player1TankMove() {
    // some code that defines the movement and shooting of the Tank
}

func player2TankMove() {
    // some code that defines the movement and shooting of the Tank
}
}
```

There would be ten of these classes (Player1, Player2, Player3...) where the player1TankMove() methods for each class would be completely different from one another.

As you can see, I'm using a delegate from the GameScene to connect the TankMove() functions so that they can be used inside that class:

```
protocol gameSceneDelegate {
    func player1TankMove()
    func player2TankMove()
}
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { ... //entire GameScene code
```

My question is, how do I set the proper class when I transition from the MainMenuViewController to the GameScene class?

Would I use lazy instantiation? If so, how would I declare it 'lazily' if I don't know which class/swift file (Player1.swift, Player2.swift, etc.) I'll be accessing?

Is there a better way to do this?

Currently I can access the proper player1TankMove() function and the tank works properly:

```
var tank1 = Player1()
tank1.player1TankMove() // used inside the update() function
```

However, because tank1 needs to be an instance of a specific class that is unknown, I'm unsure of how to decide the type to declare. Would I need to use a typealias? Generics? It seems like this would be a fairly common problem that I know how to handle with other languages, but I'm not sure how to code it in Swift.